# How To Get All Session Message using Azure.Messaging.Servicebus in DotNet Core

Tags: .net, .net-core, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

Hii All I'm DotNet Developer Working with Azure Service Bus and Function App with Service Bus Trigger.

As In My Project I was using

**Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus**

NuGet Package. But as it is Deprecated so I've to Migrate to

**Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus**.

Earlier I was Using below code to Get Topic Session Enabled To Get All Message.

`Public Run([ServiceBusTrigger](topic, subscription,con,isSessionEnabled = True) Message mysbMsg, MessageReceiver msgReceiver) { Var all = await msgReceiver.ReceiveAsync(mySbMsg.prefetchCount); }`

But Don't Know How to implement Dame Functionality using **Azure.Messaging.ServicdBus** NuGet Package

Also How to Use/Replace MessageReceiver with New Libraries relevant Object??

How to Bind ServiceBusReceiver in Run(). Binding just like MessageReceiver

I tried ServiceBusReceiver but When I try to run project getting error message like

````
ServiceBusReceivedMessage. Make sure the parameter Type is supported by the binding. 
If you're using binding extensions (e.g. Azure Storage, ServiceBus, Timers, etc.) make 
sure you've called the registration method for the extension(s) in your startup code (e.g. 
builder.AddAzureStorage(), builder.AddServiceBus(), builder.AddTimers(), etc.)```
````

Comment: @harikrishnarajoli-mt that is not helpful at all. The OP is about Functions and Message Sessions. Don’t link to a question that will not lead him to a solution but rather confuse even more.

Comment: @Vivek, what Functions SDK are you using? (Nugget package)

Comment: @SeanFeldman Currently Using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus....that has Webjobs + Azure.messaging.servicebus

Comment: Then it's In-Proc SDK. You should still have access to the ASB SDK types and can retrieve a collection of messages but not necessarily all messages.

Answer (score 1):

In `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`, we receive messages either by using a **`QueueClient`** (or `SubscriptionClient` if you are targetting a subscription) or the **`MessageReceiver`**.

In `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus`, The dedicated class `ServiceBusProcessor` process your message and error handlers to provide the same simple way to process your messages as **message handlers** in the previous packages, with **auto-complete** and **auto-lock** renewal features.

The Major difference from the previous library when it comes to **receiving messages** the new library uses a separate type for received messages, `ServiceBusReceivedMessage`.

To construct a **`ServiceBusReceivedMessage`** for mocking purposes, use the **`ServiceBusModelFactory.ServiceBusReceivedMessage`** method. It is constructed only by the library and can be created for mocking using the `ServiceBusModelFactory` static class.

```cs
// create a receiver that we can use to receive the message
ServiceBusReceiver sbReceiver = client.CreateReceiver(<yourqueueName>);

// the received message is a different type as it contains some service set properties
ServiceBusReceivedMessage sbReceivedMessage = await sbReceiver.ReceiveMessageAsync();

// get the message body as a string
string body = sbReceivedMessage.Body.ToString();
Console.WriteLine(body);
```

*Refer*  [migrate **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus** to **Azure.Messaging.Servicebus**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md)

Comment: Ok Got it, thanks for Replying.

Comment: In Previous Library Package we are Using :

messageReceiver.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken).getAwaiter().GetResult():

In Newer Package I'm using like this :

messageReceiver is Object of ServiceBusMessageAction

messageReceiver.CompleteMessageAsync(msg);

This above method takes Another parameter which is CancellationToken which is None/Default . 

So is there any Difference if i mention Token or without token. I tested but Found No Difference.

Or is there any other method which is same as CompleteAsync(string token) ??